# Debian Wheezy no sound through jack output

Tags: audio, debian, debian-wheezy, headphone-jack

I have strange problem with sound on my Debian wheezy powered notebook. Sound is not playing through jack output, but speakers are working just OK.

```
lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)


cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: IDT 92HD75B3X5
Codec: LSI ID 104


    aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

My ~/.acoundrc

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}
ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}
```

A have checked if Headphone output is not muted in `alsamixer` too.

Is there a possibility to automatically switch to JACK when headphones is connected? It worked on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Does it work if you connect external speakers instead? I assume you've tested that the headphones work right? Are you using alsa or pulseaudio? Check the sound options in `pavucontrol` if the latter.

Comment: Yes I have tested external speakers instead with no success. I tried `pavucontrol` too, but only internal speakers are working.

Comment: OK, just a shot in the dark here but these are the sound related modules currently running on my Debian : `snd,snd_pcm,snd_hwdep,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_usb_audio` try loading (`modprobe`) each of them just in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Wheezy on an eeepc. 
It turned out to be a configuration problem. This is how I solved it:

1. Open **alsamixer** in a terminal
2. Press **F6: select sound card**. 
   I had two choices: a) default b) HDA Intel. 
   Highlight HDA Intel and press enter
3. More configuration options should now be available in alsamixer
4. Press the **right-arrow key** until you find an option named **auto-mute**
5. **Enable** auto-mute

Hope it helps