# No sound in headphone jack

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, alsa

Worked fine a week ago. Yesterday when I plugged headphones into my Asus laptop, I got sound both from headphones and speakers. Today after system crash (not sure what was the reason) when I plug headphones, speakers are muted automatically but there is no sound from headphones.

```
# lspci -v
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 124d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at f7a10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC270 Analog [ALC270 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I've found [few suggestions](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2011/03/msg02273.html) to add `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` or `options snd-hda-intel model=laptop` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. I did that too, restarted `alsa-utils` but that didn't help at all.

Also tried [this](https://superuser.com/a/659573/175067) superuser answer already. No luck either - auto mute is enabled. Also channels aren't muted:

```
┌───────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.0.25 ──────────────────────────────┐
│ Card: HDA Intel PCH                                  F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: Intel PantherPoint HDMI                        F2:  System information │
│ View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All             F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: Master [dB gain: -16.50]                       Esc: Exit               │
│                                                                              │
│    ┌──┐       ┌──┐       ┌──┐       ┌──┐       ┌──┐                          │
│    │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                          │
│    │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                          │
│    │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                          │
│    │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                          │
│    │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                          │
│    │  │       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                          │
│    │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                          │
│    │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                          │
│    │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                          │
│    │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                          │
│    │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│       │▒▒│                          │
│    ├──┤       ├──┤       ├──┤       └──┘       └──┘       ┌──┐     Enabled   │
│    │OO│       │OO│       │OO│                             │MM│               │
│    └──┘       └──┘       └──┘                             └──┘               │
│     49      100<>100   100<>100   100<>100   100<>100                        │
│<  Master  >Headphone   Speaker      PCM     Mic Boost    S/PDIF   Auto-Mute  │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Basically I'm using vanilla Debian Wheezy with all updates installed. Everything worked fine few days ago. I can't recall if I installed any alsa related updates recently.

Comment: Run `alsamixer` in a terminal. Verify that the output channels aren't currently muted (use `M` to switch mute on/off). Let me know if that helps and if it does help I'll type up a proper answer. :) (ALSA often defaults to muted, and if your audio settings get reset for any reason -- which they shouldn't -- it's easy to get tripped up by that.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling channels aren't muted.

Comment: Aw drat. Well, it was worth a shot. Can't think of anything off the top of my head, then.

Comment: I had a similar sort of problem a while back, and the "fix" was to replace the defective jack (i.e., new mobo under warranty from HP).  It was a hardware problem, not a software or driver issue. You could try booting with a Knoppix or Ubuntu LiveCD and see if you get the same results; this might help point towards a hardware issue, rather than software.

Comment: @DarkMoon damn, that's not the answer I was hoping to read :( Did you have the same symptoms? Sound from both, speaker and headphones and then only speaker?

Comment: Well, I only had sound going to both, and then called HP to fix. It possibly didn't progress far enough to only be the speaker. And like I said, try booting a LiveCD of some sort and see if it's still a problem. If it is, then it's probably a hardware fault. Otherwise, it's configuration.